# Same code on two repos, how do you do that on git?

Tags: git

We've inherited a strange project. It's PHP, Zend framework and consists of modules. There are two separate sites (but connecting to the same DB) and two git repositories — the public site and the CMS. Most of the code is different, but the Base module appears to be exactly the same on both repositories. It contains the entities and services that are used in both public and administrative sites.

Is there any sane method to keep working like that? Keeping most of the code separate, but one directory exactly the same on two repos? Can I commit the same code to two repos IF that code is in a certain directory?

Unfourtunately I have no option to ask the previous developers what, how and why were they doing. But inspecting the git logs I see that, for example, one repo is updated on 15:23:23 and the other received the same commit at 15:24:28.

Could that be some dev tool, CI system, git feature? Or is it most likely that the code was manually copied over from one repo to the other?

Comment: My first idea will be to try with `git format-patch SHA1_OF_COMMIT > /tmp-dir/tmp-file` on the repo you create the commit and `git am <  /tmp-dir/tmp-file` on the repository you want to tranfer the commit. This will works nicely if the directory structures are the same for the modified files.

Comment: @Jona thanks, the directory structures are the same on the shared files. The only limitation would be that I should only work either in that special directory or outside it, right?  And that's still something manual to remember on each commit :(

Comment: If a commit contains modifications in shared files and repo specific files, there are options for `git am` and `git apply` (like `git apply --reject`, `--include`, `--exclude`) to apply portions of patch. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply

Comment: Is it fits to you to move this part to separate repo and use as [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Answer (score 0):

Git's internals are based on hash IDs.  If otherwise-identical-seeming commits have different hash IDs, they are different commits, and hence represent different history.

It's impossible to say precisely how this sort of thing came about, and in many ways that's not really an interesting question.  The interesting question is what, if anything, you would like to *do* about it.  As [Leszek Mazur suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171890/same-code-on-two-repos-how-do-you-do-that-on-git#comment109958719_62171890), this sort of thing is where Git's submodule system can be useful.

(I would say "shines" but submodules never *shine* :-) )

> Can I commit the same code to two repos IF that code is in a certain directory?

Not really: commits are full snapshots of all files.  You can of course copy the directory around; that works fine.  As others suggested, you can also turn a commit into a change-set—`git format-patch` and `git diff` do this—which you can then apply in another repository with a different history.  You can even combine the two repositories into a single repository with both histories, and use `git cherry-pick` across the two.  It's all a bit messy however you do it.